# How to create a Custom Content Type instance within a SharePoint List programmatically?

Tags: xml, web-services, sharepoint, html

As you may know, in SharePoint you can create a List Content Type (e.g. "Web folder") then add some columns for this content type (e.g. Name and Path).

How to create a custom Content Type instance within a SharePoint List?

My List is like below

```
ProductList
  WebFolder1
    Page1.aspx
    Page2.aspx
  WebFolder2
    Page3.aspx
```

I'm using the below xml to be passed to the sharepoint web service and i'd like to create a new "Web folder" under the WebFolder1:

```
<Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
<Field Name="FSObjType">1</Field>
<Field Name="Name">TestWebFolder11</Field>
<Field Name="BaseName">WebFolder1/TestWebFolder11</Field>
</Method>
```

And it creates a Folder content type under WebFolder1, whereas I'd need to create a "Web folder" content type instead.

How to create a custom content type instance programmatically?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Simply, there is a fieldname called "ContentType" which can be set:

```
<Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
<Field Name="ContentType">Web folder</Field> // this is case-sensitive
<Field Name="BaseName">WebFolder1/TestWebFolder11</Field>
</Method>
```

so other properties are not required and the name of the my webfolder becomes "TestWebFolder11" and will be located under the "WebFolder1".